# How to sudo using another user's account password from a script?

Tags: shell, sudo, root, privileges

I have a bash script running as `user`, a user account with no evaluated privileges. The machine has a second account `admin` which has sudo privileges. There is no root password set.

The script knows the account password for `admin`. How do I escalate the script up to `root`?

`sudo -S` only handles the case of escalation using your *current* account's password, such as `admin` to `root`, but `user` is unprivileged, so this won't work.

`su admin` works but provides no way to take a password from STDIN.

To rephrase, how can I achieve the below programmatically?

```
$ su admin
Password: ******
$ sudo command
Password: ******
```

Comment: To preempt comments: Yes, I know storing passwords in a shell script is bad practice. It's part of an overall solution that is even messier.

Comment: Can you add `user` to the sudoers file?

Comment: @Rocket, That would require root access, which is what I'm trying to get in the first place. This is for bulk deployment of an install script, otherwise I would just do it manually.

Comment: Is there is no `root` password set, would `su root` (or just `su`) work?

Comment: @Rocket, there is no root password set. Also, `su` password entry can't be done programmatically.

Comment: (That should've said `If there...`), but the point was, since is there no `root` password, wouldn't `su root` *not* ask for a password and possibly just work?

Comment: @Rocket, login is denied to password-less accounts, which is the entire point behind Ubuntu not having root passwords.

Comment: Ah!  Darn it.  I didn't realize that.  Sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `su` only reads from a TTY, you'll have to give it one. If GNU screen is available, try something like this:

```
screen -d -m -S foo su -c 'sudo my_command' admin
screen -S foo -X stuff 'admin_password
'
```

Line 1 sets up a session that runs the specified `su` command, which will prompt for the `admin` user's password. Lines 2 and 3 "stuff" the password (and the trailing newline to simulate pressing enter, watch the quotes) into the named session; the waiting `su` will receive it from the pty and, assuming it's correct, execute the command specified (`sudo my_command`).

(I'm sure something similar can be done with tmux, but I don't use that, so can only point to the man page. Alternatively, you could use the opportunity to learn pty programming and write your own program to do just the password-to-su passing :) )

Answer (score -1):

Though not exactly what you're looking for, one workaround is to give limited sudo permissions to the user.

Add `user` to `/etc/sudoers` with only permission to run `sudo` as user `admin` and to run command `sudo`. Example:

```
user   ALL = (admin) /bin/sudo
```

Then, run something like `sudo -u admin sudo commands`.

Comment: More sudo information, for people like me who don't want to read the `man` page: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18880/58455

Comment: If he could edit the sudoers file, he wouldn't need to do the indirection in the first place.